# PHP if...else, if echo does not register

Tags: php

I'm trying to use `if...else` with 'yes' 'no' radio buttons.  For some reason though, 'if' code gets ignored and 'your quote will be delivered to the postcode provided' comes up regardless if 'yes' or 'no' is chosen.  Where did I go wrong?

```
<?php
$delivery = 'unchecked';

$delivery = 'delivery';

if ($delivery == 'no') {

  echo "Collection from bottleneck, littlebeck!";

} else {

  echo "Your quote will include the delivery to the postcode you provided";

}

// creating cover for all unchecked 

if (isset($_POST['delivery'])) {
  $delivery = $_POST['delivery'];

  if ($delivery == 'Delivery') {
    $delivery = 'checked';
  }
}

// creating 'insert' statement 
$sql = "INSERT INTO cupcake(delivery, additionalInformation, postcode ) VALUES          ('$delivery', '$additionalInformation', '$postcode')";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) 
{
  die('Error:' .mysql_error ());
}


mysql_close();
?>
```

...instead second echo 'delivery to your postcode included ' comes up.

Comment: Keep at it these are really small errors, and your already on the right track coming here, for help.

Answer (score 4):

You have

```
$delivery = 'delivery';

if ($delivery == 'no')
```

So `$delivery` is always the string `delivery` and never the string `no`, so it always goes to the `else`.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. I  tried adding $noDelivery but with extra name the 'either or' properties of yes and no were disabled , as you then chose both if you wanted? and besides i was still having the same problem as before with it going straight to else.  If you get a chance could you mind giving me an example of if ...else in code? for 'yes/no' radio?  I posted my solution below, but though it does the job i suspect it's not quite on the money? thank you

Answer (score 2):

Id change this

```
$delivery = 'unchecked';



$delivery = 'delivery';

if ($delivery == 'no') {

echo "Collection from bottleneck, littlebeck!";

} else {

echo "Your quote will include the delivery to the postcode you provided";


}

// creating cover for all unchecked 

if (isset($_POST['delivery'])) {
$delivery = $_POST['delivery'];

if ($delivery == 'Delivery') {
$delivery = 'checked';
}
}
```

to something like this

```
<?php
$checked = false;
$delivery = isset($_POST['delivery']) ? $_POST['delivery'] : false;

if (!$delivery) {
    echo "Collection from bottleneck, littlebeck!";
}else if($delivery == 'Delivery'){ //make sure casing is right ( delivery is not equal to Delivery - this is why i suggest using boolean below, or numbers even text can be more complicated to check )
    $checked = true;
} else {
// do we want it checked or do we want it delivered -- not sure from your code but this might be redundant with the above elseif 
    echo "Your quote will include the delivery to the postcode you provided";
}

// creating cover for all unchecked


if ($checked) {
    //do some stuff
}
```

Explanation:  don't be afraid of using more variables.  Use boolean ( true and false ) whenever you can.  Separate your initialization ( the default and assignment part ) from the logic ( the decision part )  from the results part ( output etc.. ).  Then it will flow like a poem.  Granted it's not always possible, but always keep it in mind.

Initialize 
Decide 
Execute

Comment: Thanks, I think for this post it is more important to show the flow and give a few simple tips, the errors were really small ones, but the code structure is a mess.  Once that is cleaned up you can easily see the logical problems.

Comment: Thanks Artistic this is way over my head, but I'll look into why it's a better way!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value of the selected radio and put it in the delivery variable, or use it directly to check if isSelected or not

Answer (score 0):

As dave pointed out, your if statement is wrong. But to answer your question about checkboxes, if you have a checkbox like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="delivery" value="deliver!" />
```

You'll check if it's checked by using either:

```
if(isset($_POST['delivery']))
```

if it's a POST, or:

```
if(isset($_GET['delivery']))
```

if it's a GET.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where $delivery would be assigned to 'no' - so 'else' will always be returned.

I suggest try more explicit variable names and don't re-use them. Also remember the order in which code is executed in php.

Comment: Perhaps OP has a very basic understanding of PHP and the string misunderstanding is unrelated.. And remember the order in which code is executed, how is that?

Comment: php reads the file at compile time, then executes it at runtime.

Unconditional function declarations are read at compile time, so that functions are already known when your code is executed.

Comment: Giving us or spaghetti code mantle, it is listed in the documentation -Functions need not be defined before they are referenced, except when a function is conditionally defined as shown in the two examples below. And still you should not be assigning and then re assigning variables to multiple strings without additional input

Answer (score 0):

Thank you people for all your useful feedback.  I think I understand where I went wrong now ! Can't wait to try these things you suggested tonight, the first time I'll get a chance unfortunately ( UK time ) will post a feedback on what happened :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it to do what I want , in case someone finds it useful , beware though, even with the useful feedback as above, I'm still feeling my way in the dark, if copying do it with caution

.html form

```
    <form method="post" action="postcode.php">
    <p>Will You Require Delivery? <p>Yes<input type="radio" name="delivery"  value="yes"/>      <p>No<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="no"/></p>

    <br/>

    </form>
```

.php form...

```
    // below enterubg values from the form

    // this is the new piece of code that IS WORKING :)))

    if ($_POST['delivery'] == "yes")
    {
    echo "Thank you. Your quote will include the delivery charge to the postcode you    provided";  
    }
    else if ($_POST['delivery'] == "no")
    {
    echo "Thank you, pick up from little beck humperding-dong!";
    }


    /* my previous  code that wasn't working :(((( 

    $delivery = 'unchecked';



    $delivery = 'Delivery';


    if ($delivery == 'Delivery') {

    echo "Your quote will include the delivery to the postcode you provided";

    } else {

    echo "Collection from bottleneck, little beck!";


    }
    */

    // creating cover if unchecked 

   if (isset($_POST['delivery'])) {
   $delivery = $_POST['delivery'];

   if ($delivery == 'Delivery') {
   $delivery = 'checked';
   }
   }



   // creating 'insert' statement 
   $sql = "INSERT INTO cupcake(delivery) VALUES     ('$delivery')";
   if (!mysql_query($sql)) 
   {
   die('Error:' .mysql_error ());
   }


   mysql_close();
   ?>
```